# Parsing string as json python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have this as JSON string:

```
{common:{rq:{ct:""},up:"chg",down:"chr",linktargetInternal:"",hash:"",dfp:"ad-g.doubleclick.net/adi/com.gf.option_chain/default;fe=nasdaq;ft=aapl;sz=300x250;dcopt=ist;myd=ad"},stickyUrlArgs:"",option_chain:{expiry:{y:2012,m:4,d:27},expirations:[{y:2012,m:4,d:27},{y:2012,m:5,d:19},{y:2012,m:6,d:16},{y:2012,m:7,d:21},{y:2012,m:8,d:18},{y:2012,m:10,d:20},{y:2013,m:1,d:19},{y:2014,m:1,d:18}],puts:[{cid:"1101041109949338",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00470000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.01",cs:"chr",c:"-0.01",cp:"-50.00",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:"-",vol:" 360",strike:"470.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"202440188791400",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00475000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:"-",vol:" 9",strike:"475.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"383449077769463",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00480000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-0.50",cp:"-96.15",b:"0.01",a:"0.03",oi:" 6539",vol:" 1318",strike:"480.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"889017006863464",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00485000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-0.47",cp:"-95.92",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:" 2412",vol:" 765",strike:"485.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"809609994087128",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00490000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-0.63",cp:"-96.92",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:" 4662",vol:" 938",strike:"490.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"509564982113916",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00495000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-0.85",cp:"-97.70",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:" 3033",vol:" 1150",strike:"495.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"419949964472999",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00500000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.01",cs:"chr",c:"-1.24",cp:"-99.20",b:"0.01",a:"0.02",oi:" 5601",vol:" 1906",strike:"500.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"202052946910835",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00505000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-1.43",cp:"-98.62",b:"0.02",a:"0.03",oi:" 3484",vol:" 1171",strike:"505.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"93740945301328",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00510000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.03",cs:"chr",c:"-2.07",cp:"-98.57",b:"0.02",a:"0.03",oi:" 5120",vol:" 1621",strike:"510.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"397285244548765",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00515000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-2.63",cp:"-99.25",b:"0.02",a:"0.04",oi:" 4093",vol:" 1437",strike:"515.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"16957499670867",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00520000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.04",cs:"chr",c:"-3.36",cp:"-98.82",b:"0.03",a:"0.04",oi:" 11178",vol:" 5775",strike:"520.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"525313553769499",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00525000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-4.50",cp:"-98.90",b:"0.04",a:"0.05",oi:" 8721",vol:" 3763",strike:"525.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"951857154849141",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00530000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-5.30",cp:"-99.07",b:"0.04",a:"0.06",oi:" 8168",vol:" 4986",strike:"530.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"718770452910534",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00535000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.05",cs:"chr",c:"-6.90",cp:"-99.28",b:"0.04",a:"0.06",oi:" 4335",vol:" 1221",strike:"535.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"774022499704621",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00540000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.06",cs:"chr",c:"-8.74",cp:"-99.32",b:"0.05",a:"0.06",oi:" 6030",vol:" 3706",strike:"540.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"696114851470847",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00545000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.06",cs:"chr",c:"-10.49",cp:"-99.43",b:"0.05",a:"0.08",oi:" 4236",vol:" 2561",strike:"545.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"583611645155653",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00550000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.09",cs:"chr",c:"-12.51",cp:"-99.29",b:"0.07",a:"0.09",oi:" 9703",vol:" 3359",strike:"550.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"958645382056052",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00555000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.10",cs:"chr",c:"-14.49",cp:"-99.31",b:"0.08",a:"0.11",oi:" 3806",vol:" 2205",strike:"555.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1067017333626905",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00560000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.12",cs:"chr",c:"-16.73",cp:"-99.29",b:"0.10",a:"0.14",oi:" 6498",vol:" 3725",strike:"560.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"486002069484262",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00565000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.14",cs:"chr",c:"-18.66",cp:"-99.26",b:"0.14",a:"0.16",oi:" 3540",vol:" 3225",strike:"565.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"407904477888034",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00570000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.22",cs:"chr",c:"-21.24",cp:"-98.97",b:"0.18",a:"0.20",oi:" 2858",vol:" 4259",strike:"570.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"886872871436931",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00575000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.24",cs:"chr",c:"-23.76",cp:"-99.00",b:"0.23",a:"0.28",oi:" 2457",vol:" 4153",strike:"575.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1020383070407573",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00580000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.37",cs:"chr",c:"-27.22",cp:"-98.66",b:"0.37",a:"0.40",oi:" 3336",vol:" 10895",strike:"580.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"32608930043617",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00585000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.58",cs:"chr",c:"-30.17",cp:"-98.11",b:"0.54",a:"0.58",oi:" 2060",vol:" 11331",strike:"585.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"673943550096411",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00590000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.01",cs:"chr",c:"-33.94",cp:"-97.11",b:"0.95",a:"0.99",oi:" 1846",vol:" 12239",strike:"590.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"814317887488205",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00595000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.72",cs:"chr",c:"-37.13",cp:"-95.57",b:"1.72",a:"1.85",oi:" 1317",vol:" 11221",strike:"595.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"999379436557563",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00600000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.10",cs:"chr",c:"-39.97",cp:"-92.80",b:"2.98",a:"3.10",oi:" 1871",vol:" 27631",strike:"600.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"930882674562505",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00605000",e:"OPRA",p:"5.00",cs:"chr",c:"-42.40",cp:"-89.45",b:"4.80",a:"4.90",oi:" 731",vol:" 19072",strike:"605.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"522292664419639",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00610000",e:"OPRA",p:"7.60",cs:"chr",c:"-44.58",cp:"-85.44",b:"7.20",a:"7.35",oi:" 1232",vol:" 19836",strike:"610.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"832192968237765",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00615000",e:"OPRA",p:"10.60",cs:"chr",c:"-45.40",cp:"-81.07",b:"10.20",a:"10.35",oi:" 424",vol:" 10995",strike:"615.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"641374961973721",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00620000",e:"OPRA",p:"14.30",cs:"chr",c:"-47.20",cp:"-76.75",b:"13.75",a:"14.00",oi:" 605",vol:" 5852",strike:"620.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"551837487018071",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00625000",e:"OPRA",p:"18.55",cs:"chr",c:"-47.70",cp:"-72.00",b:"17.80",a:"18.10",oi:" 463",vol:" 2868",strike:"625.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"494094908784693",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00630000",e:"OPRA",p:"22.15",cs:"chr",c:"-49.01",cp:"-68.87",b:"22.25",a:"22.55",oi:" 915",vol:" 1427",strike:"630.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"78456659414535",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00635000",e:"OPRA",p:"26.45",cs:"chr",c:"-50.23",cp:"-65.51",b:"26.95",a:"27.25",oi:" 470",vol:" 1339",strike:"635.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"998402428386783",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00640000",e:"OPRA",p:"32.59",cs:"chr",c:"-48.94",cp:"-60.03",b:"31.80",a:"32.10",oi:" 219",vol:" 1103",strike:"640.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"718028293542302",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00645000",e:"OPRA",p:"37.35",cs:"chr",c:"-49.61",cp:"-57.05",b:"36.70",a:"37.00",oi:" 239",vol:" 593",strike:"645.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"621420610238806",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00650000",e:"OPRA",p:"41.85",cs:"chr",c:"-49.94",cp:"-54.41",b:"41.65",a:"41.95",oi:" 169",vol:" 512",strike:"650.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1085118967280351",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00655000",e:"OPRA",p:"43.95",cs:"chr",c:"-52.05",cp:"-54.22",b:"46.60",a:"48.15",oi:" 74",vol:" 21",strike:"655.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"688688418770738",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00660000",e:"OPRA",p:"43.00",cs:"chr",c:"-55.75",cp:"-56.46",b:"51.55",a:"53.15",oi:" 122",vol:" 10",strike:"660.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"379931605145805",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00665000",e:"OPRA",p:"104.66",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"56.50",a:"58.25",oi:" 190",vol:"-",strike:"665.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"535854637184025",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00670000",e:"OPRA",p:"60.65",cs:"chr",c:"-52.05",cp:"-46.18",b:"61.50",a:"63.25",oi:" 154",vol:" 33",strike:"670.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"812450412279605",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00690000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"81.45",a:"82.25",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"690.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"556414072823908",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00695000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"86.45",a:"87.30",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"695.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1018302976621110",name:"",s:"AAPL120427P00700000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"91.50",a:"92.35",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"700.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"}],calls:[{cid:"632054413311661",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00470000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"136.00",a:"140.20",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"470.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"381996683377403",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00475000",e:"OPRA",p:"-",c:"-",b:"131.00",a:"135.25",oi:"-",vol:"-",strike:"475.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"592083992249997",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00480000",e:"OPRA",p:"129.90",cs:"chg",c:"+48.90",cp:"60.37",b:"126.70",a:"130.10",oi:" 49",vol:" 15",strike:"480.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"537775007944930",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00485000",e:"OPRA",p:"79.30",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"121.00",a:"125.10",oi:" 15",vol:"-",strike:"485.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"774107117572822",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00490000",e:"OPRA",p:"127.00",cs:"chg",c:"+57.15",cp:"81.82",b:"116.00",a:"120.10",oi:" 41",vol:" 1",strike:"490.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"116425734542348",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00495000",e:"OPRA",p:"65.35",cs:"chb",c:"0.00",cp:"0.00",b:"111.20",a:"115.10",oi:" 28",vol:"-",strike:"495.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"665829597100461",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00500000",e:"OPRA",p:"107.00",cs:"chg",c:"+46.00",cp:"75.41",b:"106.70",a:"110.10",oi:" 257",vol:" 107",strike:"500.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"721805009229803",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00505000",e:"OPRA",p:"106.28",cs:"chg",c:"+49.78",cp:"88.11",b:"101.75",a:"105.10",oi:" 118",vol:" 27",strike:"505.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"841091536145869",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00510000",e:"OPRA",p:"99.00",cs:"chg",c:"+47.00",cp:"90.38",b:"96.70",a:"100.10",oi:" 58",vol:" 36",strike:"510.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"167209408101096",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00515000",e:"OPRA",p:"98.65",cs:"chg",c:"+48.55",cp:"96.91",b:"92.70",a:"93.70",oi:" 52",vol:" 16",strike:"515.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"282456284579406",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00520000",e:"OPRA",p:"90.50",cs:"chg",c:"+46.42",cp:"105.31",b:"88.00",a:"90.15",oi:" 528",vol:" 115",strike:"520.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"705719208406389",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00525000",e:"OPRA",p:"82.42",cs:"chg",c:"+42.66",cp:"107.29",b:"83.00",a:"85.15",oi:" 508",vol:" 161",strike:"525.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1110078313809143",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00530000",e:"OPRA",p:"77.47",cs:"chg",c:"+40.82",cp:"111.38",b:"77.85",a:"78.85",oi:" 787",vol:" 194",strike:"530.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"145486713613185",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00535000",e:"OPRA",p:"74.10",cs:"chg",c:"+41.73",cp:"128.92",b:"73.05",a:"75.20",oi:" 516",vol:" 280",strike:"535.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"435352834451474",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00540000",e:"OPRA",p:"67.50",cs:"chg",c:"+38.75",cp:"134.78",b:"68.25",a:"69.95",oi:" 1004",vol:" 535",strike:"540.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"180249016896121",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00545000",e:"OPRA",p:"64.13",cs:"chg",c:"+38.88",cp:"153.98",b:"63.20",a:"63.55",oi:" 1205",vol:" 196",strike:"545.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"610656331883822",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00550000",e:"OPRA",p:"57.50",cs:"chg",c:"+35.15",cp:"157.27",b:"58.05",a:"58.40",oi:" 3802",vol:" 1521",strike:"550.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"968369661656696",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00555000",e:"OPRA",p:"53.00",cs:"chg",c:"+33.15",cp:"167.00",b:"53.05",a:"54.30",oi:" 2217",vol:" 929",strike:"555.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"83540594843416",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00560000",e:"OPRA",p:"49.15",cs:"chg",c:"+32.25",cp:"190.83",b:"48.25",a:"49.00",oi:" 5801",vol:" 3622",strike:"560.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"106186090110341",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00565000",e:"OPRA",p:"43.00",cs:"chg",c:"+28.90",cp:"204.96",b:"43.20",a:"43.70",oi:" 3688",vol:" 2231",strike:"565.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"386583721896453",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00570000",e:"OPRA",p:"38.07",cs:"chg",c:"+26.37",cp:"225.38",b:"38.35",a:"38.65",oi:" 6019",vol:" 5389",strike:"570.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"68408993828531",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00575000",e:"OPRA",p:"33.31",cs:"chg",c:"+23.66",cp:"245.18",b:"33.45",a:"33.70",oi:" 6863",vol:" 3485",strike:"575.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"970432890843055",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00580000",e:"OPRA",p:"28.00",cs:"chg",c:"+20.20",cp:"258.97",b:"28.60",a:"28.90",oi:" 7825",vol:" 5886",strike:"580.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"113079500710791",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00585000",e:"OPRA",p:"23.59",cs:"chg",c:"+17.28",cp:"273.85",b:"23.80",a:"24.05",oi:" 4866",vol:" 3687",strike:"585.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"429127815175915",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00590000",e:"OPRA",p:"18.90",cs:"chg",c:"+13.90",cp:"278.00",b:"19.15",a:"19.50",oi:" 6666",vol:" 6223",strike:"590.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"98053040849539",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00595000",e:"OPRA",p:"14.80",cs:"chg",c:"+10.68",cp:"259.22",b:"15.00",a:"15.30",oi:" 6360",vol:" 4939",strike:"595.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"847879903642354",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00600000",e:"OPRA",p:"11.40",cs:"chg",c:"+8.05",cp:"240.30",b:"11.25",a:"11.40",oi:" 20500",vol:" 24484",strike:"600.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"493508780275580",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00605000",e:"OPRA",p:"8.15",cs:"chg",c:"+5.53",cp:"211.07",b:"8.20",a:"8.30",oi:" 6169",vol:" 13027",strike:"605.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"917142414424387",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00610000",e:"OPRA",p:"5.60",cs:"chg",c:"+3.60",cp:"180.00",b:"5.65",a:"5.75",oi:" 8056",vol:" 32736",strike:"610.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"634566486905303",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00615000",e:"OPRA",p:"3.70",cs:"chg",c:"+2.09",cp:"129.81",b:"3.65",a:"3.70",oi:" 6150",vol:" 32860",strike:"615.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"133143669759594",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00620000",e:"OPRA",p:"2.22",cs:"chg",c:"+0.92",cp:"70.77",b:"2.14",a:"2.23",oi:" 8699",vol:" 33982",strike:"620.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"637411413026419",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00625000",e:"OPRA",p:"1.32",cs:"chg",c:"+0.37",cp:"38.95",b:"1.30",a:"1.34",oi:" 4931",vol:" 18524",strike:"625.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"483636393022716",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00630000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.77",cs:"chg",c:"+0.02",cp:"2.67",b:"0.75",a:"0.79",oi:" 7691",vol:" 22980",strike:"630.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"73739304533457",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00635000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.48",cs:"chr",c:"-0.15",cp:"-23.81",b:"0.44",a:"0.48",oi:" 4824",vol:" 15750",strike:"635.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"180177410166341",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00640000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.31",cs:"chr",c:"-0.18",cp:"-36.73",b:"0.28",a:"0.33",oi:" 6073",vol:" 10876",strike:"640.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"19825572955515",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00645000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.25",cs:"chr",c:"-0.20",cp:"-44.44",b:"0.21",a:"0.25",oi:" 4528",vol:" 4602",strike:"645.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"575813409851817",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00650000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.18",cs:"chr",c:"-0.24",cp:"-57.14",b:"0.15",a:"0.19",oi:" 8850",vol:" 7417",strike:"650.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"814165890839215",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00655000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.16",cs:"chr",c:"-0.20",cp:"-55.56",b:"0.13",a:"0.16",oi:" 4154",vol:" 2996",strike:"655.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"1110891062035830",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00660000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.10",cs:"chr",c:"-0.17",cp:"-62.96",b:"0.10",a:"0.12",oi:" 2468",vol:" 1771",strike:"660.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"700745049654457",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00665000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.08",cs:"chr",c:"-0.13",cp:"-61.90",b:"0.08",a:"0.09",oi:" 1754",vol:" 1785",strike:"665.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"901579155762872",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00670000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.07",cs:"chr",c:"-0.12",cp:"-63.16",b:"0.07",a:"0.08",oi:" 9257",vol:" 2370",strike:"670.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"79250146044172",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00690000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.04",cs:"chr",c:"-0.01",cp:"-20.00",b:"0.02",a:"0.04",oi:"-",vol:" 915",strike:"690.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"707565651200933",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00695000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.04",cs:"chr",c:"-0.01",cp:"-20.00",b:"0.01",a:"0.04",oi:"-",vol:" 218",strike:"695.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"},{cid:"683263003794090",name:"",s:"AAPL120427C00700000",e:"OPRA",p:"0.02",cs:"chr",c:"-0.03",cp:"-60.00",b:"0.01",a:"0.04",oi:"-",vol:" 267",strike:"700.00",expiry:"Apr 27, 2012"}],underlying_id:"22144",underlying_price:610.27002}}
```

I am not able to parse this in python.. Please help!
It is picked from Javascript 
it was like var A =

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: You can use http://jsonlint.com to validate JSON and see where the issues are.

Comment: This common data format should be called pidgin-on

Comment: Tried YAML, doesnt work..
Any more suggestions? It was picked from Javascript
var A = {common......}

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your time... I got it sorted! Used regular expressions to change it to json format :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is not JSON.

In JSON all strings must be surrounded by double-quotes. This is an example of a valid JSON object:

```
{
    "common": {
        "rq": {
            "ct": ""
        },
        "up": "chg",
        "down": "chr",
        "linktargetInternal": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time... I got it sorted! Used regular expressions to change it to json format :-)

Comment: You used regular expressions? I think it must be easier i you just open a chrome/firefox console and write:  "JSON.stringify(myJSobject)"

Comment: The task needed it... I need to store the data in MySQL DB via Python..
I couldn't think of any other technique..
You could suggest anything?